# forEach angular loop

Tags: angular, moltin

```
data:(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
included:{brands: Array(2), main_images: Array(4)}
```

I am currently logging that to the console. However within data is my products name and within included in my products href to their respective images.

In my .ts file:

```
 getAllProducts() {
    this.mhttp.allProducts()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.names = data.data;
        this.products = data.included.main_images;
        console.log(data);
      },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

in my html file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 products" *ngFor="let product of products">
          <div class="image">
            <img [src]="product.link.href">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 products" *ngFor="let name of names">
          <div class="name">
            <a routerLink="/product/viewProduct/{{name.id}}">
              <h3>{{ name.name | uppercase }}</h3>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

at the moment I am looping through my images and them my product names, so the product names are not underneath they product images.

It came to my attention that forEach loops will be best. But I am not 100% sure how to forEach loop through different objects.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong here. Are you getting an error is something not working? Perhaps I just don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: can you tell what final `array` you are expecting ? I am assuming that `data` has `4` products , but the `included` has just **2**  brands. Its better if you can share the json structure and what you want it to be after transformation

Comment: Yes its working but not displaying correctly. the ngFor loop is running through the images and the product names separately, which means that there are 2 rows of project images and then two rows of project names.the project names are not displaying underneath each product image.

Comment: @ShashankVivek yes the data consist out of 4 products, but in the included main_images is where these 4 product images are saved. so I am looping through 2 different arrays trying to use it as one object. thus I must loop through images and names separately, where I wish to loop through one object  in the html

Comment: Create a demo on stackblitz.com or provide the json data for a solution

Comment: So I am going to explain the best possible way: currently I am logging out two arrays, `data` and `included`. With my for loop I am getting the product name within `data` and the product image within `included`. The problem is I am doing two ngFor loops to get info out of two different objects. Thus I somehow want to make one ngfor loop or foreach loop to get `data.name` and `data.images`. where I currently have to get `product.image` and `name.name`. I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question was asked long ago, but after reviewing my questions ond stackoverflow I remembered the solution was to map the two objects into one:

```
getAllProducts() {
    this.mhttp.allProducts()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.products = data;
        this.prodList = this.products.data.map((itm, i) => {
          return {
            title: itm.name,
            imgUrl: this.products.included.main_images[i].link.href,
            price: itm.meta.display_price.with_tax.formatted,
            id: itm.id
          };
        });
        console.log(this.products);
      },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine them into one array using something like the below.

```
   getAllProducts() {
    this.mhttp.allProducts()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.products = data;
        this.productList = this.products.data.map(product => {
        //get the image id out of the product object
          const imageId = product['relationships'].main_image
            ? product['relationships'].main_image.data.id
            : false
            //now loop through and match them to the included data
           return {
            ...product,
            //id from product id to the the id of the included then add to product
            image: imageId
              ? this.productIncluded['main_images'].find(img => img.id === imageId).link.href
              : '/static/cat.svg'
            }
          }),
    error => {
      console.log(error);
        });
     }
```

Then in your html everything should be in the product list array to be used.

Comment: tried to copy your code as I am not sure what you are doing. But it failed